# Free compiler + IDE for writing Windows App in C++ (for students)

Tags: c++, ide

I will be teaching middle school and high school students C++ over this summer vacation.
I went to a bookstore, browsed through some of recommended C++ books such as C++ Primer, The C++ Programming Language, Thinking in C++ and I have strong confidence that my students will lose interest quickly when they read those books :)
It will be 2 hours a week for 8 weeks program so I don't have much time and the main goal will be to get students excided about writing app and also have them somewhat prepared for AP computer class for the next semester (thus C++ intead of C# or Java)

I myself learned programming using MFC first. I didn't know anything about C++ but followed Sam's teach yourself on VC++ MFC and the idea of being able to write an app where I can click on a button and have it pop up "hello world" was so much cooler then boring console app. If I started from console app with black screen and white text, i probably won't be doing software for living today.

So I was going to teach MFC to my students. I won't go in too deep into MFC as the focus will be on C++ and to make students excited about programming....Until i realized that Visual studio express doesn't include MFC.

It would be great if there is C++ compiler, IDE and framework that my students can use for free and be able to create a windows dialog app.
Thanks!

Comment: Code::Blocks and Qt Creator are both good options for this I think. There's definitely others too

Comment: Repost this at [programmers@stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Off-topic here.

Comment: thanks Alexey, your comment was so much more useful then just giving it -1.

Comment: Code::Blocks seem promising. thanks

Comment: funny, the question I asked at programmers@stackexchange got migrated back to stackoverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663805/free-compiler-ide-for-writing-windows-app-in-c-for-students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Code::Blocks. It is a free and open source, cross-platform IDE which supports multiple compilers including GCC and Visual C++.

Code::Blocks 12.11 is the latest stable version.