# Free compiler + IDE for writing Windows App in C++ (for students)

Tags: c++, ide

I will be teaching middle school and high school students C++ over this summer vacation. I went to a bookstore, browsed through some of recommended C++ books such as C++ Primer, The C++ Programming Language, Thinking in C++ and I have strong confidence that my students will lose interest quickly when they read those books :) It will be 2 hours a week for 8 weeks program so I don't have much time and the main goal will be to get students excided about writing app and also have them somewhat prepared for AP computer class for the next semester (thus C++ instead of C# or Java)

I myself learned programming using MFC first. I didn't know anything about C++ but followed Sam's teach yourself on VC++ MFC and the idea of being able to write an app where I can click on a button and have it pop up "hello world" was so much cooler then boring console app. If I started from console app with black screen and white text, i probably won't be doing software for living today.

So I was going to teach MFC to my students. I won't go in too deep into MFC as the focus will be on C++ and to make students excited about programming....Until i realized that Visual studio express doesn't include MFC.

It would be great if there is C++ compiler, IDE and framework that my students can use for free and be able to create a windows dialog app. Thanks!

Comment: [Qt](http://qt-project.org) is a good, and reasonably popular, option.

Comment: If it's only Windows, use Microsofts [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products), which is free (Google: 2seconds)

Comment: @thorstenmüller: Note the op's mention of MFC.  I personally wouldn't be teaching MFC to today's students, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Both Netbeans and Eclipse have C++ plugins available, if memory serves correctly.  You could probably use either GTK+ or QT for your GUI library.  Not sure I'd go with MFC...

Comment: Also, see here: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B.  Code::Blocks might be interesting: http://www.codeblocks.org/, though I've never used it myself

Comment: I would hate someone who would force MFC on me.

Comment: I'm pertty sure there are full Visual Studio license programs for students.

Comment: not sure why it got migrated from programmers.stackexchange.com because I initially asked the question at stackexchange and people wanted it to be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com. seems like there isn't any consistent rule here?

Comment: @thorstenmüller: read my question. I did mention Visual Studio Express (question: 30 seconds)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free compiler + IDE for writing Windows App in C++ (for students)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653199/free-compiler-ide-for-writing-windows-app-in-c-for-students)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a book like "Head First C" the Head First series has a lot of pictures and it is really interesting to read because it has a lot of humor. Although they do not have a C++ book. It would be worth checking out so you can get a better idea on how to explain things differently.

I personally love these books because like I said it has a lot visual stuff to think about. If you are thinking of teaching OOP concepts then the Head First OOAD is a must in my opinion.

I'm not sure if there are free C++ IDE to create windows console apps. There free IDE's to create C++ applications, but for Windows specific. I dont think there is. I am pretty sure if you contact microsoft they may be able to give you free licenses. since you will be teaching at a k-12 school. However, the Visual Studio Express version is free, so that should be enough to get you started.

If you want all the bells and whistles then the Pro version is the way to go, but it may take contacting Microsoft to get it for free.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out *Accelerated C++*? It was a textbook of modern C++, written for beginners.

[http://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-Practical-Programming-Example/dp/020170353X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X)

I am not sure whether teaching GUI programming for beginners is a good idea. GUI programming, by its very nature, is more complicated. If you really want to have a try, Codeblocks is a cross-platform IDE built around wxWidgets, which is a decent open-source GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

MFC is rather old and Forms programming under Windows using Visual Studio is the current practice using C++/CLI which is an extension to c++ and would have to be learned but is a similar syntax to c++.

If your interest is in Visual Studio, that is the way I would go unless the Express editions are undesirable and you could go with an open source IDE/Compiler using Eclipse C++ CDT and MinGW.  There is also CodeBlocks and a few other opensource and free IDEs in which your students can write c++ code.

I also plug

[C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113)

as a book I am learning c++ with.

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks and Turbo C are one of the most commonly used IDEs.

Code blocks is an open source program and also a cross-platform and completely free. The compiler is really scalable and widely fast. The debugger is really easy to understand and is also great for beginner programs